# Create Dynamic Modal Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng, ngfor

I have a list of elements from a service, so I need to send the name and other properties to a modal onclick event for every element, I have this code. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Can't you pass them as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onclick of the item, pass the items information to the `showDialog` method. In you dialog display the information passed as follows:

```
<h2>{{this.profileSelected}}</h2>

<p (click)="showDialog(item)"></p>
```

In your component create a member variable profileSelected to store the item clicked as follows:

```
showDialog(item){
    this.profileSelected = item;
    this.display=true;
}
```